# expressjs optional url parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, url

I'm trying to make simple app based on expressJS to return users (like API).
I have /users route to get all users, which is ok.

```
app.get('/users', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response)
```

I need to add an optional parameter limit not to output all records. For example:

```
app.get('/users?limit=5', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response)
```

but limit param should be **optional**, so URLs like **/users** or **/users?limit=5** or **/users/limit/5** will be working.

Thank you.

Comment: Please have a look at this url. I hope you can get the answer .
https://flaviocopes.com/express-get-query-variables/

Answer (score 1):

Don't modify the name of the route at all.

`app.get('/users',` will match `/users` with or without a query string.

Access data in the query string via [`req.query`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query).

```
if (typeof req.query.limit !== 'undefined') {
    // a limit has been requested
}
```

Answer (score -1):

using `app.get('/users?limit=5', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response)` as route is a good way; you can provide the parameter or not when calling it.

(I don't know ho to do it in express/node but i reference it with php laravel to just show you the logic)

So in your controller you put condition to make the query chosen executed; you store the prepared query inside variable:

```
$query = Model::myqueryBuilder();
```

so putting condition like

```
if($request->limit) {
    $query = $query->limit($request->limit);
}
```

if you have another parameter you can make another condition; and in the end of our all parameter condition you execute the query

```
$query->get();
```

so you can conditionally use some query builder and execute all query prepared in the end.

I hope this logic helped you

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to create two endpoints. 
First endpoint for `'/users'` and `'/users?limit=5'`

```
app.get('/users', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    const { limit } = req.query
    console.log(limit)
})
```

Second endpoint for `'/users/limit/5'`

```
app.get('/users/limit/:limit', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    const { limit } = req.params
    console.log(limit)
})
```